# Number of real values of $x$ in $[-2\pi,2\pi]$ for which the value of the expression $y=\sqrt{2\sin x}-\sin x$ is maximum,is

Tags: trigonometry

Number of real values of $x$ in $[-2\pi,2\pi]$ for which the value of the expression $y=\sqrt{2\sin x}-\sin x$ is maximum,is
$(A)0$
$(B)2$
$(C)4$
$(D)$more than $4$

---

$y=\sqrt{2\sin x}-\sin x$ is maximum if $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$
$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2\cos x}{2\sqrt{2\sin x}}-\cos x=\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{2\sin x}}-\cos x=0$ if $\cos x=0$ or $\sin x=\frac{1}{2}$
This gives us $8$ values of $x$,four from $\cos x=0$ and four from $\sin x=\frac{1}{2}$.But the answer given in the book is $4$,i dont know where i am wrong.

Comment: Hint: Condition $y'=0$ gives maxima **and** minima. You should use $y''$ to exclude the minima, and you have to check that the function is defined at the arguments from $\cos x = 0.$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\sin x \geq 0 \Rightarrow x \in [0,\pi]\cup [-2\pi, -\pi]$. Using AM-GM inequality: $\sqrt{2\sin x}-\sin x = \sqrt{1\cdot  2\sin x}-\sin x \leq \dfrac{1+2\sin x}{2} - \sin x= \dfrac{1}{2}$, and this is the maximum, and it occurs when $1 = 2\sin x\Rightarrow x = \dfrac{\pi}{6}, \dfrac{5\pi}{6}$. Thus these are the values of $x$ for which the maximum occurs, also taking $x \in [-2\pi, -\pi]$, you would have a total of $4$ answers. Thus $C)$ would be the best choice.

Comment: Four is the correct answer. You forgot that  the domain is $[-2\pi..2\pi]$

Comment: And $[-2\pi, -\pi]$